# Will split question feature be useful?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

I often encounter situation when a new user is posting several absolutely non correlated questions as a single quetion. As the result we get a bunch of non-enlightening answers which are very short since they try to cover all the OP's question. Even more one can answer only a part  of this questions but do not do this, because he is supposed to completely answer the whole list of OP's question. I suggest to request this feature, and what is more I think it will be useful for all SE sites.

Comment: Who will own these new questions? The mod / high rep user performing the split, or the original poster? Presumably, the poster. Then it's a fundamental change of the way SE operates: someone will be able to create a question and assign its ownership to me. I do not like this.

Comment: When someone posts several question in one, I tell him/her not to.

Comment: And what ususaly that people do?

Comment: Related: [Posting multiple questions as one?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one)

Comment: Sorry, Norbert, I haven't been able to keep track of what people do when I ask them not to post multiple questions in one. Sometimes, they get multiple answers before they can even read my comment, which sort of makes my comment moot. By the way, if you want to be sure I read something addressed to me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, I see people not enthusiastic about my idea.

Comment: @user53153 These new questions could be owned by the Community user.
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, I don't think this is useful.**

I think a better response to such questions is to leave a comment suggesting that the questions be posted separately, and that the current question be deleted.  You can punctuate this with a downvote and/or a vote to close.

It is better for the asker to do the work of splitting the question.  If someone else does it, errors could be introduced or necessary context omitted.

Comment: Asker won't do the splitting, because in most cases author of such questions are newbies that will visit this site only once.

Comment: Well then, they won't get an answer, and their question will probably be closed, and that's just too bad.  If someone else is interested in one of the questions, they can ask it themselves.

Comment: Then what is the purpose to leave such a trash on site, if you are sure that it will be closed/non-answered/downvoted ?

Comment: @Norbert It does not have to stay on the site. Closed questions can be deleted with 3 votes to delete. Unanswered questions with $\le 0$ votes are automatically deleted after a year.

Comment: @Norbert And unanswered questions with $<0$ votes are deleted after only a month. [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/206169)

Answer (score -1):

I think we should just go ahead and delete all the subsequent unrelated questions in the post, and leave a comment asking the OP to ask them as separate questions. (It would be considerate to add a link to the original version in the edit history, so they can easily copy the contents to new questions.) The result is that (i) we have a single well-defined question which can be answered reasonably, and (ii) the asker is motivated to do the work of splitting the question themselves if they want answers to the other questions. It's a win-win!

This is [the last part of Phira's suggestion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6536/856) on how to deal with multiple unrelated questions in a single post.

Comment: I consider removing substantial parts of a post as over-editing.

Comment: @5PM: My view is that the reason over-editing is harmful is because it may change the meaning of the post and result in a different question being answered than the one intended by the asker. This is not likely to happen in this case. But I can see that the rest of the community does not share my enthusiasm for this solution.